# How to pass variables to the template parameter in azure yaml?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have template

```
dockerbuild.yml

steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Build an image to container registry
    inputs:
      script : echo $(PATH)
```

then a variable file

```
var.build.yml
- name: PATH
  value: 'docker/path'
- name: PATH1
  value: 'docker/oldpath'
- name: PATH2
  value: 'docker/newpath'

azurepipeline1.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: components/pipeline_templates
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: PoolA

variables:
- template: variabletemplates/var.build.yml@templates

jobs:
  steps:
      - template: CI-CD/dockerbuild.yml@templates  # Template reference  
        parameters:
          PATH: ${{ variables.PATH }}
      - template: CI-CD/dockerbuild.yml@templates  # Template reference  
        parameters:
          PATH: ${{ variables.PATH1 }}
      - template: CI-CD/dockerbuild.yml@templates  # Template reference  
        parameters:
          PATH: ${{ variables.PATH2 }}
```

The above code works

But if I change the parameter to

```
    parameters:
      PATH: ${{ variables.PATH1 }}
       OR
    parameters:
      PATH: ${{ variables.PATH2 }}
```

In the output it shows

```
 Output:
   docker/path
    $(PATH1)
    $(PATH2)
```

I need to reuse the template with many times within the pipeline with different paths. Please help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your template needs a `parameters` block.

```
parameters:
  - name: PATH
    type: string

steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Build an image to container registry
    inputs:
      script : echo ${{ parameters.PATH }}
```

Comment: you are "The MAN". thanks mate it worked for me

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar, on your var.build.yml file what does that look like? Can you share it without all the sensitive data?